# Finding LU factorization and one number is off

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I'm trying to find LU of this 2x2 matrix, but when I check my work, the bottom right number is 31 instead of 1.
A is the matrix at the top.
What am I doing incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: $U$ should have $(1 - 16) = -15$ in the lower-right.

Comment: Ohhh. I thought it was the other way around. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considere $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 8 \\
4 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} $
Then we do 
$A(-2) _{1,2}$ the elementary operation.
Then we have 
Considere $U= \begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 8 \\
0 & - 15\\
\end{pmatrix}$
THEN 
$L=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
2 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix} $
And 
$$LU=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1& 0 \\
2& 1\\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 8 \\
0 & - 15\\ \end{pmatrix} =A$$